# How to filter folder heading display in iframe

Tags: iframe

I am displaying the contents of a folder on my server on a web page, but the heding detail is showing in the iframe.

I want only the .mp3 file detail showing as in this image [detail of required infornmation in iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxXGk.png)

Comment: I found this site showing how to style a folder heading, but could not get it to work https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, from the link I posted https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/ you download the file from the link at the bottom of the page.

Then upload contents to server, then edit the .index.php file to remove all the text responsive headings, then place this modified file in the server directory with the .mp3 files and it shows only the .mp3 files as links, perfect!

Comment: Thanks that works good, how do I hide the .htm files and the.php file in the list?